# Nativescript - Changing the launch screen

Tags: nativescript

There is a way to change de launch screen without have to change each image one by one? 
Like the doc says I used the tool: `http://nsimage.brosteins.com/` to change the icon, but to change the splash screen I have to change 20 images, there isn't an easiest way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to do this; is on the community site...
http://nativescript.rocks

Actually the images sub-site specifically.
http://images.nativescript.rocks
It will allow you to post a single image and it will generate all the proper size screens for both android and ios.

The second way to do it is to use the `ns` command line (`tns` was renamed to `ns` in late 2020)

```
ns resources generate splashes ../SourceImage.png --background "#FFFFFF"
```

You want to use a source image of at least 1024x1024 as Apple requires this for the main app page image, otherwise you will be missing this size and you won't be able to submit the app to Apple.

---

Please note: no matter which way you generate your screens; you should always DE-INSTALL the app from your test devices so that it can do a full reinstall so that you do see the new splash screens.

---

Disclosure:
I'm the developer of http://nativescript.rocks group of sites.

Comment: This is what I was looking for!! Thanks for all!!

Comment: What means "do a full rebuild" like says on the page? I changed all the images, removed the platform added ios again and installed it again but I get the nativescript splash screen.

Comment: Typically it is: `tns run android --emulator` or `tns run ios --emulator` (drop the emulator if sending to a real device.  )   If you attempt to use the LiveSync command it doesn't work.  So a "run" typically rebuilds the entire app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have to uninstall the app and restart the phone... Thanks!

Comment: Great Work, Thanks!

However you might want to update your app, since I got this error: "Error: The resource name must start with a letter"

Comment: Actually it's not only that, in order to make it work, I had to rename all photos to "icon" & "logo" in order to replace the initial files of nsvue. Still good work.

Comment: 2021 here, your solution is outdated.

Comment: @user2401543 - Nope, my solution still works.     However, one thing to note, is you should de-install the app from the device to see the new screens.

Comment: It does not update a launch screen on my iPhone11, it does for iPad.

Comment: I have heard that some devices have to be restarted as the OS caches the splash screen.  So try de-install; reboot, install, run.

Answer (score 10):

With NativeScript 4.x.x and above the CLI has introudced a command for automatic generation of splash screen for both iOS and Android.

```
tns resources generate splashes ../myImage.png --background "#FF00FF"
```

The above will take the `myImage.png` and create different scaled images and replace them in `splash_screen.xml. It will also produce a background PNG with the desired background color. More about this feature [in the official documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/configuration/resources/resources-generate-splashes).

Comment: can we create a splash screen just with image and no background color not even white ?